# Rendering data with html tags (rendering them)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am reading some data from the database where the content contains html tags such us `<p></p>`

**Example**:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of pageData">
 <h3>{{ data.title}}</h3>

 <div class="content">
   {{ data.content}}
 </div>

</div>
```

The problem is that the content of data.content is:

```
<p>Here is some text</p>
```

And the page is displaying the `<p></p>` too.

I don't want the `<p>`'s the show but to render as html.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can bind to innerHtml Property

```
<div class="content" [innerHTML]="data.content"></div>
```